# C++/CLI Service, run as console app during Debug

Tags: visual-c++, windows-services, c++-cli

I am trying to build a new windows Service that i can run as a console App during debug. My thought is that i would need instantiate the service class and spit all output to the console.

So instead of using the below call it would be the new instance.

```
ServiceBase::Run(gcnew myWinService());
```

Currently it is a skeleton and just want to get some insight on this. Thanks!

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    if (argc >= 2) {
        if (argv[1][0] == _T('/'))
            argv[1][0] = _T('-');

        if (_tcsicmp(argv[1], _T("-Install")) == 0) {
            array<String^>^ myargs = System::Environment::GetCommandLineArgs();
            array<String^>^ args = gcnew array<String^>(myargs->Length - 1);

            // Set args[0] with the full path to the assembly,
            Assembly^ assem = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();
            args[0] = assem->Location;

            Array::Copy(myargs, 2, args, 1, args->Length - 1);
            AppDomain^ dom = AppDomain::CreateDomain(L"execDom");
            Type^ type = System::Object::typeid;
            String^ path = type->Assembly->Location;
            StringBuilder^ sb = gcnew StringBuilder(
                        path->Substring(0, path->LastIndexOf(L"\\")));
            sb->Append(L"\\InstallUtil.exe");
            Evidence^ evidence = gcnew Evidence();
            dom->ExecuteAssembly(sb->ToString(), evidence, args);
        }
    } else
        ServiceBase::Run(gcnew myWinService());
}
```

Comment: @0A0D: not a duplicate.  The referenced question is about launching another program from a windows service.  This question is about running the *same* program as a service or as a regular process depending on release/debug mode.

Comment: You could use an `#ifdef` so the relevant code gets compiled/does not get compiled.

Comment: @Merlyn: yes, except that it's rather delicate if all of OP's code is in `myWinService`, as you would have to invoke the different event handlers manually.

Comment: @Andre: Yes, he'd probably have to make a big refactor.  Throwing implementation directly in a framework's callbacks tends to make your application less easily portable...

Comment: @Merlyn: in this case, it means you're re-implementing part of the framework to re-use you code, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* wanted to, you could simply replace the call to `ServiceBase::Run()` with custom code that invokes the service methods.  As the `On*()` service notification handlers are protected, this would basically require a workaround, such as a public method of `myWinService` that automates the proper calls to the notification handlers.

However, this is a really bad idea and feels somewhat hack-ish.  You should really write a second program that executes whatever is usually done in the service's background thread (which you probably launch in the `OnStart()` method) in synchronous mode.

Basically, make two programs that put the relevant boiler-plate code for the process type and have them invoke the same code, which really contains your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is some ability to interact with the console from a service. In the Windows service properties dialog look for a check box named 'allow interaction with console".

You might also consider putting the majority of your application in an assembly/dll and calling the functions from either a console application or the windows service.